# Cannot run "npm run watch", error message brings up "gulp" error

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, node-modules, browser-sync

I am using a web starter kit from coding phase GitHub that normally works fine for me. for some reason when i attempt to run npm run watch it gives me error messages. I'm not 100% positive but I believe this begun when I updated my I did an uninstall and re-install of nodeJS. help me out!

```
sh: gulp: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! starter-kit-2019@1.1.0 watch: `gulp`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the starter-kit-2019@1.1.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/joseperez/.npm/_logs/2018-12-20T02_45_19_840Z- 
debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because we are using 'gulp' as a global module. So when you removed node from your system, it removed the gulp which is a package installed.

You can reinstall it by using

```
`npm install gulp-cli -g`
```

And it will work!

**Update:**
He is using  a mac so try running this command.

```
$ npm uninstall --global gulp gulp-cli
$ rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/gulp.1
$ npm install --global gulp-cli`
```

Comment: Try running "gulp" in your terminal! See if it works or not. I think the installation of gulp have some issues. Try uninstall the package then reinstall as in the given answer. It can be done by npm uninstall gulp-cli. And have you run npm install inside the project?

Comment: correct I am running npm install inside the project as well. when I do check to see the version of "gulp -v" installed it is also giving me an error of "command not found"

Comment: So the installation of gulp didn't worked. Try reinstalling the gulp. And check the node version.

Comment: I uninstalled all of that Im not quite sure why it still gives me problems after reinstalling

Comment: Can you comment the log after gulp-cli installed. I can help you after that.

Comment: /Users/joseperez/.npm-global/bin/gulp -> /Users/joseperez/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
+ gulp-cli@2.0.1
updated 1 package in 10.217s

Comment: Finally i understood that. Its because you are using windows machine and you need to setup ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE. You can refer to this link on how to do that. And can you accept the answer.  https://www.journaldev.com/7402/node-js-environment-setup-node-js-installation

Answer (score 0):

Hope this info turns out useful to someone after doing research on an error that was coming up on my console stating, "gulp: command not found" I found a link that addresses how to fix this. turns out my gulp was not installing properly because there was an issue with my path. btw I am using a Mac machine below is the link that helped me out!

[here is the link that helped me out!](http://webbb.be/blog/command-not-found-node-npm)